# Linq how include works in query expression

Tags: c#, linq, include

Well i am in a situation where i need to filter object by children properties. 
This is my query :

```
 from q in _db.Questions
 where q.Answers.Count() > 0
 from a in q.Answers
 where !excludeAnswerIds.Any(m => m == a.Id)
 select q;
```

_db is just an object for connect to database :

```
EFDbContext _db = new EFDbContext();
```

I am using eager loading, do i need to include answers for e.x :

```
from q in _db.Questions.Include(a => a.Answers)
```

or it would work either way? 
excludeAnswerIds is just `List<int>()`

Comment: Why don't you just run your code and try it? :)

Comment: There is a big data and it would be tiresome. Also i want to know how exactly query expression works in this situation

Comment: `Include` is an optional feature, queries work w/o it. It's you who is deciding if you need it or not.

Comment: @IvanStoev `Include` is optional if he not turn off `LazyLoading`, right?

Comment: It's eager loading but seems work in query expression ... In lambda expresion it doesn't work

Comment: @jbueno He said *"I am using eager loading"*

Comment: @ucnobiucnobi What's the real issue? You want to `Include` but it's not working?

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry, I missed that. So, I can't understand his real issue...

Comment: There is no issue, i just want to understand exactly in query expression need or not include, in this case i don't need but sometimes it throws an exception to split queries into small parts